# Material UI Autocomplete not updating options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make API calls to my backend and fetch suggestions as the user types into the input. Here's what I have:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [
  fromOptions,
] = useSelector(({ search: { fromOptions } }) => [
  fromOptions,
]);

  const handleFromChange = useCallback(
    async (event, value) => {
      console.log('event', event);
      console.log('value', value); // prints
      if (!value || value?.length < 3) {
        if (fromOptions.length) {
          dispatch({
            type: SET_FROM_OPTIONS_DELIVERY,
            payload: [],
          });
        }
      } else {
        const query = {
          params: {
            query: value,
          },
        };

        const { data } = await axios.get(api.GET.GET_OPTIONS, query);
        dispatch({
          type: SET_FROM_OPTIONS_DELIVERY,
          payload: data,
        });
      }
    },
    [fromOptions],
  );

<Autocomplete
    options={fromOptions}
    onInputChange={(event, value) => handleFromChange(event, value)}
    onChange={() => console.log('selected!!')}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
    style={{ width: window.innerWidth * 0.2 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Combo box' variant='outlined' />}
/>
```

The `const { data } = await axios.get(api.GET.GET_OPTIONS, query);` part is reached when expected, correctly having had retrieved the data/suggestions, but when I set `fromOptions` in my dispatch action, it does not update the drop down. Performing an onBlur of the Autcomplete component followed by an onFocus seems to render the fetched suggestions, but I obviously can't expect the user to do this. How can I force a rerender on the fly?

[CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-rgb-jend4?file=/src/App.js:0-926)
You could look at the console and see that the `options` array changes as the user types, but the drop down options change only on onBlur followed by an onFocus again.

Comment: I found your sandbox to be a difficult example to work with since it randomly chose options that didn't necessarily match the typed input. Here is a modified version of your sandbox that produces options that are more related to the input and it seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-options-b1qe5..

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue any solution for this issue? @Mike K

Comment: @RutvikPrajapati there was a prop called something like `CustomListBox` or `renderBox` and I just ended up providing a custom component that did nothing but return the list. Weird solution, but it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue in `@mui/material: 5.11.6` with preventing `Autocomplete` from filtering options internally, by overriding `filterOptions` with non-filtering method `filterOptions={(options) => options}` (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/).

This workaround allowed me to fetch remote options list with `%searchtext%` inputValue.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Issue seems to persist in `@mui/material: ^5.14.18`